# how to provide dependency injection for class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm struggling with this concept of dependency injection. Here is one of the articles I am reading:

https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/dependencyinjection/implementation-asp-net-core-mvc

Here is the first part of my class:

```cs
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public Mailgun(IConfiguration configuration) 
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}
```

**IConfiguration** contains the connection information needed to connect to the **MailGun** API wrapper.

And here is where I tried passing the **Configuration** in `Program.cs` (mostly as it comes out of the box with a new *ASP.NET Core 7 MVC* project:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IConfiguration, Mailgun>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

This line is where I am attempting to pass the dependency above:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<IConfiguration, Mailgun>();
```

But the error is

> Error CS0311  The type 'Mailgun' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddTransient<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Mailgun' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration'.

I understand the error but do not understand how to inject `IConfiguration` into my class.

Could someone please show me how this is meant to be accomplished?

Comment: **You don't need to do anything to use `IConfiguration`.** Its implementation is assigned for you (the configuration is taken from `appsettings.json`). Just remove that line.

Comment: `AddTransient` assigns *implementation*, not class that *uses* the service.